# obtaining values from database using variable in c# console application

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have a string as c_number. i want to fetch data from my database where number is primary key. it always gives the error that c_number is invalid column. where my column name is number.

```
static void movies_on_rent()
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    try
    {
        Console.Clear();
        con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionSQL);
        con.Open();
        Console.Write("Enter Customer phone :");
        string c_number = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        reader = new SqlCommand("select * from customer_info where number=c_number", con).ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t\t{1}   {2}   {3}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt32(1), reader.GetInt32(2), reader.GetString(3));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: In that command text the string _c_number_ is nothing more than a literal string not the name of the variable whose value you want to use to query the database. You should learn how to write parameterized queries

Comment: can u tell me how to resolve it...?

Comment: There's a million questions on Stack Overflow and tutorials all over the internet on how to do this. Go and spend 30 seconds researching this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're declaring the variable. C_Number isn't assigned to anything at this point and it's not marked as value because of the lack of quotation marks (and most like the datatype you have selected for the column).

Try doing the below instead.

```
string c_number = Console.ReadLine();
using (SQLConnection con = new SQLConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionSQL))
{
      SQLCommand Command = new SQLCommand("Select * from customer_info where number=@cnumber", con);
      Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_number", c_number);
      SQLDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();

     // Now use the data reader
}
```

Also, using a "Using" statement is always recommended when the "IDisposable" interface is available.